# Can I deploy Cloud Run using Deployment Manager?

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-deployment-manager

I'm trying to figure out if I can use Google Deployment Manager to deploy a service to Cloud Run. If not is this on the roadmap?

https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/supported-resource-types